# How Do I Make A Div Clickable In Wordpress When Running Loop Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make an entire div clickable withing a loop in Wordpress

I tried wrapping an anchor link around the div using the_permalink();

```
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <div class="content-pop-children">

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


        <?php

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
            the_post_thumbnail();
        endif;
        ?>
        <header class="entry-hpop">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </header>

    <div class="cat-head">
    <!-- Output Category and Link to Cat --> 
    <a href=”<?php echo $category_link ?>”

    title=”<?php echo $category_name ?>”  >

    <?php echo $category_name ?>

    </a>
    </div>  <!-- cat-head --> 
     <!-- the custom excerpt --> 

               <?php echo $newsExerp; ?>


    </article>




       </div>  <!-- content-pop-children --> 

       </a>
```

The issue I have is that the excerpt isn't clickable, while the rest of the div isn't responding correctly.

this the result https://gyazo.com/eeace52c1803a3c8a5d004435cb704a1

the excerpt area isn't clickable, while other divs isn't responding properly, your help would be appreciated

**Edit**

I should add that, I am creating a custom excerpt where I can trim down the length of the post character, here is how it goes:

```
if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
        $arr_posts->the_post();
                        // the custom excerpt
                       $exerp = get_the_excerpt();
                      $newsExerp = strip_tags($exerp);
                      if (strlen($newsExerp) > 500) {
                       // truncate string
                      $stringCut = substr($newsExerp, 0, 500);
                        // make sure it ends in a complete word
                             $newsExerp = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).'...'; 
                                  }
```

Then I call the excerpt with `<?php echo $newsExerp; ?>`, Am I missing something?

Comment: can you show CSS code of that first div element. what css you have applied for class content-pop-children

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I am using flex - 

I have a container holding the whole post 

` .content-pop {
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    background: white; 
} `

then a children div

`.content-pop-children {
    flex: 1 0 30%;
    margin: 10px;
    border-right: 5px solid #00000047;
} `

Comment: did you open browser inspect and checked if link is there?

Comment: @yasaryousuf I inspected it, a link is there http://prntscr.com/obxx56 the excerpt isn't just clickable while the rest is clickable kind of

Comment: It looks like you have a link (<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">) which contains another link ( <a href=”<?php echo $category_link ?>” ), [you can not do this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Properties). You may want to implement this with javascript.

Comment: @JonP Yeah you are right, I have another link in there, it seems I am gonna try it using Jquery, but the problem I would likely encounter is the Cat link; not sure if that would be clickable anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try posting the DOM contents of 'content-pop-children', most likely you are forming the DOM wrongly. try this

```
<div class="content-pop-children">
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

    <?php

    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
        the_post_thumbnail();
    endif;
    ?>
    <header class="entry-hpop">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header>
    <div class="cat-head">
            <?php echo $category_name ?>
    </div>  
    <!-- cat-head --> 
    <!-- the custom excerpt wrapped in a class -->
    <div class='cat-excerpt'> 
    <?php echo $newsExerp; ?>
     </div>
    </a>
</article>
 </div>  <!-- content-pop-children -->`
```

```css
.content-pop-children
{
  flex: 1 0 30%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-right: 5px solid #000; 
}
.content-pop-children a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-pop-children">
    <article id="postID">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56928919/how-do-i-make-a-div-clickable-in-wordpress-when-running-loop-query">

        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200">

        <header class="entry-hpop">
            <h1 class="entry-title">Foo Bar</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="cat-head">
                FOO TITLE
        </div>  
        <!-- cat-head --> 
        <!-- the custom excerpt -->
        <div class="cat-excerpt"> 
       except placed here
         </div>
        </a>
    </article>
```

Comment: Wow! That's close, it's clickable now but the pointer is responding to different divs within the post, check it out https://gyazo.com/e0885dc27cf9a26d61c6007aef76b4c8 by the way, thanks, I highly appreciate that

Comment: you have a css animation (grow) on the individual divs, add the animation to the parent container (content-pop-children) instead of individual divs

Comment: That's exactly what I did,  I have a container holding the whole posts ` .content-pop { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; background: white; } ` then a children div .content-pop-children { flex: 1 0 30%; margin: 10px; border-right: 5px solid #00000047; }

This image explains better http://prntscr.com/obyqci

Comment: remove the css animation from  .content-pop and add it to each .content-pop-children . please upvote my answer if it worked for you

Comment: When I added the CSS styles to each .content-pop-children, it pushes each the post item http://prntscr.com/obz2t5

Comment: My bad, I had some CSS transform making each element scale-up, Thanks, solved

Comment: I marked your answer already, and Its a staging website, thanks once again, how can I ask you other question (CSS kinda) :)

Comment: Anytime I use this     

`<a href="<?php echo $category_link ?>" >

    <?php echo $category_name ?>
    </a>
`
It makes the excerpt non clickable, why is that

Comment: Thanks, Just post your question here , i will be sure to reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add anchor tag in article element.

```
<div class="content-pop-children">
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        <?php

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
            the_post_thumbnail();
        endif;
        ?>
        <header class="entry-hpop">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </header>
        <div class="cat-head">
                <?php echo $category_name ?>
        </div>  
        <!-- cat-head --> 
        <!-- the custom excerpt --> 
        <?php echo $newsExerp; ?>
        </a>
    </article>
</div>  <!-- content-pop-children -->
```

Comment: Can you give my edit a look, I just edited my question, thanks

Comment: it is look like some element is not closed properly check in mozila browser inspect as mozila making line red in inspect (Ctr + u) page if the element is not closing proper

Comment: BTW you can do one more simple thing check out this -  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/

Comment: Thanks, it seems I wasn't formatting the Dom content correctly, @Phemi Babs was right but the pointer is responding to different divs within the parent container, instead of a single container